# Snap raphaelJS object to a div on drag

Tags: javascript, raphael

Hay, i have a Raphael object, and a div which i want it to "snap" to. I'm using the drag event to drag an object around, but if i released the object, nothing is sent to the browser. Is there anyway to make it "snap" to a div?

Comment: Can you tell me more what you mean with "nothing is sent to the browser". What do you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Raphäel object is SVG and the div is a HTML element. You would have to transfer the divs coordinates and size to Raphäel and work with those dimensions there. They both have a DOM Base but then go off into different realms. Like fishes and birds.